# How do I assign a probability (uniform increasing or decreasing linear distribution) to a array of values?

Tags: javascript, math, numbers, probability

> Given X=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] -- **but X could be any length(N)**.
>
> I want to achieve the following:
>
> 1. I want to give the 1st value X[0], the highest probability.
> 2. I want to give the 2nd value X[1], a lesser probability than X[0].
> 3. I want to give the 3rd value X[2], a lesser probability than X[1].
> 4. ...
> 5. I want to give the Last value X[N], a lesser probability than X[N-1]
>
> **All probabilities should sum up to 1.**

For clarity with uniform probability distribution(1/(X.length)) looks like this:

{1:0.1, 2:0.1, 3:0.1, 4:0.1, 5:0.1, 6:0.1, 7:0.1, 8:0.1, 9:0.1, 10:0.1,}

If possible solution in javascript would be Great.

Comment: `uniformly` in what respect? linear? geometric? exponential?

Comment: @JaromandaX Linear, i have also updated the question title

Comment: so, an example for 3 elements would be what exactly?

Comment: {1:0.43, 2:0.33, 3:0.24} is one distrubution that is decreasing.

Comment: is that linear? - see, I think the question is vague

Comment: Real world example would be lets say 10 people waiting in line. The 1st person in line should have the highest chance of getting help and the last person in line would have the least chance of getting help. If the teller choose who to help randomly.

Comment: There is (mathematically) an infinite amount of such arrays. It isn't clear what you are asking.

Comment: In your first example, is there any importance to X[n]? It seems that just the length of the array (or the line of people in your example) matters.

Comment: @Polikdir apologizes, I agree the question is somewhat vague. the number of people in line would help how much to distribute the probability.

Comment: That was my question, I understand that the length of the array matters, but does `X[n]` (in your first example where `X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`)? Also, how would you like to distribute the probability? It could be `[0.5, 0.4, 0.1]`, `[0.99, 0.0075, 0.0025]` etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sum the indices (all values increased by one) and use the sum for calculation the probability.

For a reverse distribution, reverse the probability array.

```js
var add = (a, b) => a + b,
    data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    sum = data.length * (data.length + 1) / 2,
    probability = data.map((_, i) => (i + 1) / sum),
    sumProbability = probability.reduce(add, 0);

console.log(probability);
console.log(sumProbability);
```

Comment: Isn't it in reverse order..? You may need to change it like `probability = data.map((_,i,a) => (a.length-i) / sum);`

Comment: If possible could you explain the following line of code further: ``probability = data.map((_, i) => (i + 1) / sum);`` or the one reversing the order

Comment: @redu, the question was *uniform increasing **or** decreasing linear distribution* [emphasis by NS].

Comment: @jasan, it builds a map with every index increased by one divided by the sum.

Comment: Yes you are right though as per the header. I guess i was just caught with his #1 condition "I want to give the 1st value X[0], the highest probability."

Answer (score 1):

Let's probability for the last element is q, for previous element is 2*q, for previous is 3*q ... and for the first one is N*q

```
  q + 2 * q + 3 * q +...+(N-1)*q + N * q  = 1
  q * Sum(1...N) = 1
  q * N * (N + 1) / 2 = 1
  q = 2 / (N * (N + 1))
```

So you can find q for any sequence length and get probabilities for every element.
Example for N = 3

```
  q = 2 / (3 * 4) = 1/6
```

probabilities:

```
  3/6, 2/6, 1/6   Sum = 1
```

Comment: in your calculation for q , how did you choose the 2 and the 4. I assume the 3 is because N= 3

Comment: 2 is from formula `q = 2 / (N * (N + 1))`, 4 = N+1